# Can't show hidden files even with the 'show hidden files and folders' set

Tags: windows-server-2003

Microsoft server 2003.

There is a hidden file but I can't see it even though I have the 'show hidden files and folders' radio button set.  I am a domain admin so shouldn't have a problem.

Another user with the same permissions can see it.

What else needs to be set?

Comment: You may get better answers over on http://serverfault.com/ the sysadmin sibling of stackoverflow

Answer (score 5):

Did you also un-check the "Hide protected operating system files" option?

Comment: +1, but bear in mind that this default may be there for a reason (i.e. "mess with these files and Bad Things may happen").

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a virus activity.